# How to mock a method that doesn't have an interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit, moq

In my controller's action I am doing:

```
string a = Url.Action(...);
```

I'm using nunit and Moq (and Mvc 2)

**How could I stub the call to Url.Action to return some string?**

Comment: Can you post the definition of Url and maybe a more complete sample...  We need to know what Url.Action is.

Comment: I don't think you can, not without being able to hook into that Url class somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mock concrete classes that don't have a default Constructor with Moq (I'm assuming that Url is an instance of `UrlHelper`).  You have two options here:

(1)  Check out [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) as an alternative/supplementary mocking framework

(2)  Write a wrapper class for UrlHelper methods that implements an interface and you can then mock the wrapper for clients.

Comment: I'm astonished that Moles exists - but surely it can't 'detour' static methods with 100% reliability?  Isn't the compiler free to inline static methods, for instance?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how Moles works under the hood, but I do use it quite frequently and have had no issues "moling" static methods or otherwise "unmockable" dependencies.

Comment: Neither Controller.Url nor UrlHeler.Action are static. Both are instance members of the class. However this will not help either, because UrlHeler.Action is not virtual.

Comment: You **can** mock concrete classes that don't have a default constructor. Use the Mock constructor that takes a params array of object. Example: `new Mock<Foo>("param1")` What you **can't** do with Moq is override non-virtual or static members.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. UrlHeler.Action is not virtual, so you could not stub it with Moq.

You can however create virtual method in you controller. And replace/override it's implementation in tests.